# Standard way of working with tensorflow core

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Usually while using high level API like keras we don't define the layers parameters exclusively. But while using the tensorflow core all the models parameters and weights are defined exclusively.

```
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([filt1_features,
filt1_features, no_channels, conv1_features]))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([conv1_features]))
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([filt2_features,
filt2_features, conv1_features, conv2_features]))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([conv2_features]))
```

Also the helper functions are created :

```
 # Define helper functions for the convolution and maxpool layers:
 def conv_layer(x, W, b):
   conv = tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
     padding='SAME')
   conv_with_b = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, b)
   conv_out = tf.nn.relu(conv_with_b)
   return conv_out
 def maxpool_layer(conv, k=2):
   return tf.nn.max_pool(conv, ksize=[1, k, k, 1],
    strides=[1, k, k, 1], padding='SAME')
```

Is this the standard way of doing ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the low level api. Originally it was the only way to do things in TensorFlow. If you wish to use the low level then yes this is correct way to do it.

You get more flexibility which perhaps you want/need, but if you are just going to be working with standard layers such as pooling, conv2d, fully connected in your models then there is probably no point and you can simply use the tf.layers or tf.keras.layers api which will be quicker and less error prone than writing everything yourself.

These higher level apis will in the end do the same stuff as what you have written above, just you dont need to worry about making variables etc. yourself which speeds things up.